# Using ASP.NET Identity without direct database connection

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement ASPNET Identity on a website in my DMZ. The rule for our DMZ sites is that they cannot use database connections only services. How can I leverage ASPNet Identity without connecting to a database?

Comment: You could build something that implements [IUserStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuserstore-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2), and have that connect to anything you like. Then use that when adding Identity to your application. The answer provided below gives you the impression that Entity Framework is required, and that is *completely* wrong.

Comment: I was thinking of putting in a Web API using Identity inside my firewall and exposing it to the DMZ.  I could then call the API to do my Identity handling.  This would address the restriction of not accessing the database directly.  What I don't know is how to set up my website to use the Identity information for roles and restricting access and such.  It is straightforward if you just include Identity in your site.  The extra abstraction may not work as I am hoping.  We will see.

Answer (score 0):

From the Identity service [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

> **Persistence control**
>
> By default, the ASP.NET Identity system stores all the user
>   information in a database. ASP.NET Identity uses Entity Framework Code
>   First to implement all of its persistence mechanism. Since you control
>   the database schema, common tasks such as changing table names or
>   changing the data type of primary keys is simple to do. It's easy to
>   plug in different storage mechanisms such as SharePoint, Azure Storage
>   Table Service, NoSQL databases, etc., without having to throw
>   System.NotImplementedExceptions exceptions.

Comment: What you quoted from the docs is correct... everything else, not so much.